# where to download the android support-v4-22.2.0?

Tags: android

In my Android SDK Manager, I have installed Android SDK Build-tools from 17 to 23,  but I canot find  `support-v4-22.2.0` in the `sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4`.

```
$ ls
13.0.0  18.0.0  19.0.0  19.0.1  19.1.0  20.0.0  21.0.0  21.0.2  21.0.3  22.0.0  22.1.0  22.1.1  maven-metadata.xml  maven-metadata.xml.md5  maven-metadata.xml.sha1
```

How to install `support-v4-22.2.0.jar` use SDK manager or where can I download a `support-v4-22.2.0.jar`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Android SDK Manager:

In the new one you can find **Android Support Library rev 23** under the tab SDK Tools.

In the old one you can find **Android Support Library rev 23** at the very bottom under the Extras folder.

Just install it in the way you choose and then you can use it like

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
```

in dependencies in your app's build.grade file

Comment: I installed Support Library Rev 23, gradle still report `Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0`, and there is no 23.0.0 folder in `sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4`

Comment: Maybe I should restart Android Studio or something else. after I restarted my system, `23.0.0` came out and `gradle build` works.

Comment: glad to hear that :) You actually had to press sync in case you didn't do it for next time.